# *-network UNCLAIMED ubtuntu 20.04 Wi-Fi 6 AX200

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04, network-manager, iwlwifi

my network suddenly not working after rebooting. it was *-network DISABLED at first, but after trying things around, I messed it up and it become unclaimed.

For some pointers I've got along the way, these commands returned:

`sudo lshw -C network`

```
   *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:52:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ceb00000-ceb03fff
```

wifi is missing from here, `rfkill list all`

```
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

my device is, `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280`

```
52:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:0080]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

kernel, `uname -r`
`5.4.0-54-generic`

i don't know what is this for, but `iwconfig`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
ham0      no wireless extensions.
enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.
usb0      no wireless extensions.
```

also, this is the complete list of networking thoubleshoot

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 21 Nov 2020 11:43 WIB +0700

Booted last: 21 Nov 2020 00:00 WIB +0700

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.4.0-54-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 10:37:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V [8086:15bc] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V [17aa:229f]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e

52:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:0080]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:00bd Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b67c Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0fce:71f9 Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications AB H8314
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 17ef:6039 Lenovo Lenovo Laser Wireless Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled

##### lsmod #############################

iwlwifi               331776  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    20480  0
cfg80211              704512  1 iwlwifi
wmi                    32768  2 intel_wmi_thunderbolt,wmi_bmof

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp0s31f6' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
3: ham0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1404 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'ham0' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
4: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'usb0' [IF3]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.42.37/24 brd 192.168.42.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute usb0
       valid_lft 5188sec preferred_lft 5188sec
    inet6 fe80::88a4:3e72:9ab:3f49/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

ham0      no wireless extensions.

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.

usb0      no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.42.129 dev usb0 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev usb0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.42.0/24 dev usb0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.42.37 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         878       1  0 11:01 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         usb0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Sony Ericsson Mobile Communications AB
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        H8314
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rndis_host
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 22-Aug-2005
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               RNDIS device
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'usb0' [IF3]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/net/usb0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       usb0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 2
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       989139e2-851b-37e1-851e-8e187949768d
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3
GENERAL.METERED:                        yes (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.42.37/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.42.129
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.42.129, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.42.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 7199
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        expiry = 1605939009
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        host_name = thinkpad
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.42.37
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        next_server = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       routers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::88a4:3e72:9ab:3f49/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/20
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   989139e2-851b-37e1-851e-8e187949768d | Wired connection 2

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s31f6
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         e1000e
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 3.2.6-k
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               0.5-4
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp0s31f6' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6/net/enp0s31f6
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         ham0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           tun
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceTun
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         --
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        --
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         tun
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 1.6
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'ham0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1404
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.REASON:                         37 (NetworkManager went to sleep)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/virtual/net/ham0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    yes
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     no
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               yes
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

cat: /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state: Permission denied

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-ubuntu-fan.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices+=interface-name:fan-*

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/arte hotel.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=arte hotel | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=arte hotel
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Xperia.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Xperia | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Xperia
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/IZA 2.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=IZA 2 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=IZA
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/LESTARI 19.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=LESTARI 19 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=LESTARI 19
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/iPhone.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=iPhone | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=iPhone
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/KOS_PONDOK_IBU.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=KOS_PONDOK_IBU | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=KOS_PONDOK_IBU
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/IZA 1.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=IZA 1 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=IZA
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/LUCKY EKY.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=LUCKY EKY | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=LUCKY EKY
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Merak 33.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Merak 33 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Merak 33
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/LUCKY EKY_plus.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=LUCKY EKY_plus | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=LUCKY EKY_plus
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/IZA.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=IZA | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=IZA
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Blok E1 No 62.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Blok E1 No 62 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Blok E1 No 62
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/LESTARI 19 Lt 2.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=LESTARI 19 Lt 2 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=LESTARI 19 Lt 2
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Javadancer.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Javadancer | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Javadancer
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Jakarta (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

ham0      no frequency information.

enp0s31f6  no frequency information.

usb0      no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

ham0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp0s31f6  Interface doesn't support scanning.

usb0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-54-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-50.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-50.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-50.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-so-a0-jf-b0-50.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-cc-a0-50.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-b0-jf-b0-50.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-50.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-50.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-50.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-50.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-a0-hr-a0-50.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-b0-hr-b0-50.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-QuQnj-f0-hr-a0-50.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-jf-b0-50.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-Qu-a0-hr-a0-50.ucode
srcversion:     B6DF401BA0F55B3F4BFBFC5
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           iwlwifi
vermagic:       5.4.0-54-generic SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        47:AF:FC:F1:86:66:29:ED:36:CF:32:E5:45:0F:C1:C8:85:38:3E:AF
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      20:90:E6:56:2B:A6:CF:8A:50:50:5D:EB:88:AF:D3:E0:87:17:8E:88:
        DF:8F:AD:1E:99:4D:36:9B:BA:BB:43:12:43:48:06:F1:FA:43:43:23:
        0F:68:B7:41:1C:67:CA:93:63:8D:95:6F:3C:7F:7E:B7:3B:D8:83:39:
        83:3B:48:AC:23:4A:B3:23:A1:C0:6D:3A:89:CF:DB:CE:87:02:28:76:
        B2:E3:D8:77:98:CD:51:68:48:45:C0:32:0C:AE:0C:4F:CA:B7:0B:5A:
        3F:37:46:7D:AC:A8:A6:F3:29:AB:BD:B2:05:C7:26:A5:76:99:67:70:
        A3:46:9A:04:A7:34:73:FE:89:ED:4F:1F:87:BE:89:CB:31:DE:B8:B8:
        28:8F:EB:1A:2F:CA:68:E2:0F:74:8B:BD:FD:57:CF:89:ED:56:37:DC:
        A3:A5:1A:42:5A:93:13:66:F1:0B:FD:7D:7D:86:3B:20:02:87:DB:CD:
        4F:B0:09:77:A2:1B:B9:74:CF:EE:AA:FB:51:48:59:38:3C:48:F1:CA:
        A5:29:29:FA:FB:52:56:F4:04:EB:FD:35:35:5A:0B:EE:E2:90:6E:C7:
        1C:0B:B2:B2:11:65:2A:28:0A:7D:B0:FD:19:C0:68:51:75:45:2D:64:
        5C:8E:FF:27:17:BE:79:B4:62:CD:99:EE:07:0A:B9:48:54:51:95:DC:
        D9:DB:7C:B2:6B:CA:FC:78:69:54:69:7B:7D:3A:18:C3:67:83:E8:14:
        C9:2F:34:A9:FA:42:9A:3E:E3:1C:D9:31:F1:C6:E6:D7:14:B6:BC:06:
        F6:35:78:1E:8B:21:EC:56:0F:27:BF:D8:CC:57:60:3E:E9:AB:2B:6A:
        29:52:D2:F0:88:A7:C9:56:AA:7C:FA:63:0D:21:08:C5:92:FC:A2:08:
        B0:83:62:36:75:DF:10:30:A7:11:91:7C:38:7D:86:0A:B8:D4:AA:EE:
        A6:91:3D:27:C6:6B:75:9E:97:E0:20:17:93:F1:32:75:46:90:BE:38:
        91:79:C1:E5:53:AB:4A:C0:3E:95:19:8F:30:73:0F:BD:F1:BF:22:56:
        7E:0E:8E:91:F2:A3:5E:CC:0D:B3:09:2B:0C:A8:73:8D:E2:53:A6:E2:
        C0:C1:FD:22:1A:41:2E:3F:51:BB:AD:CD:B3:8D:D8:41:DB:58:5A:36:
        11:87:52:6A:2D:D4:FE:5E:18:DF:99:CD:45:E6:60:59:30:27:12:90:
        1B:40:2E:5A:E4:33:9C:3F:8E:3A:5C:A7:DD:F0:B1:D1:F6:B0:8B:A2:
        E2:A6:4E:CB:83:1F:FC:B6:A9:C0:BA:7D:32:EA:F9:FF:99:05:3F:34:
        15:EC:0B:22:EA:A4:14:1B:41:69:40:CD
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 2K for AX210 devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K 4: 2K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           enable_ini:Enable debug INI TLV FW debug infrastructure (default: 0 (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm:           remove_when_gone:Remove dev from PCIe bus if it is deemed inaccessible (default: false) (bool)
parm:           disable_11ax:Disable HE capabilities (default: false) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-54-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     CE7EB7DD73B1F1EBDD3970C
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.4.0-54-generic SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        47:AF:FC:F1:86:66:29:ED:36:CF:32:E5:45:0F:C1:C8:85:38:3E:AF
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      69:0F:FE:36:4B:AB:72:95:61:E9:7E:F7:64:26:00:C2:4B:18:A3:C3:
        96:87:FA:4F:6F:11:7C:36:DB:E2:12:EB:9A:1E:6A:DD:9E:C8:A4:88:
        FD:2C:E9:58:EE:0D:B7:F3:AA:4B:FE:21:79:8D:F6:D8:99:BE:46:A9:
        7C:33:A6:A4:AB:1D:95:36:73:E1:4B:C1:C5:03:BE:D1:DC:BB:9E:78:
        2A:A0:F3:BB:6F:C2:14:48:70:A3:3F:93:CE:B3:C5:5F:5F:86:8A:03:
        DD:28:59:AC:92:BB:A2:98:F2:2D:94:5B:63:15:FF:84:79:CC:C9:B9:
        2B:54:02:BC:0E:5C:F8:21:F1:1F:3E:11:48:25:71:47:A8:66:9F:F5:
        92:7A:07:D4:35:64:E9:9C:46:C2:75:EF:A9:88:A3:87:A6:5A:72:69:
        A9:19:58:06:DB:77:E0:AC:57:A6:F4:9E:08:6A:85:13:E5:25:C3:B6:
        72:31:CD:28:03:A1:B2:C2:B5:B5:9B:2B:A5:69:A2:DD:2A:BC:E9:BE:
        49:1A:B1:26:9D:5F:6B:A2:E4:BA:33:BA:76:63:9C:11:DD:EE:90:2C:
        82:16:9B:F0:A9:47:E0:76:62:A3:4A:71:BC:B6:75:8E:3B:ED:F8:E8:
        4B:6E:3B:47:02:84:6D:0A:1A:3B:F1:D8:90:4B:81:A6:FD:50:20:07:
        94:DF:3D:65:DD:E3:06:78:8F:2D:AB:F3:D4:DD:83:DE:00:5F:01:21:
        E5:B2:B2:EC:D4:2F:FC:59:DE:B5:62:47:6C:BD:98:8E:B9:74:B8:15:
        41:7A:89:5F:EB:73:B9:F8:2F:AD:C9:57:C2:EE:A9:23:F9:51:A9:DB:
        4E:8D:D7:D8:A4:61:F2:DF:3B:62:43:12:60:1A:FA:89:9E:95:59:29:
        FC:8E:B1:33:E5:9A:C5:15:E7:58:31:44:A3:D4:30:48:31:D6:D6:4A:
        AD:90:5D:1C:8C:95:AB:19:41:3F:A5:13:35:48:2A:98:22:9F:78:FF:
        D1:E4:F1:5E:B5:E2:B2:4E:E0:B6:29:26:A1:D3:0B:07:74:CF:D3:A8:
        0A:A3:D7:93:D3:D2:F0:5F:57:1B:E7:6E:A2:7D:25:E0:DE:41:6C:7F:
        72:37:D5:07:FF:63:C9:94:B2:45:DB:D5:A8:C8:CE:5A:83:81:C5:F4:
        2B:E6:6F:6D:C2:22:BF:ED:8A:0C:5B:32:3A:61:DA:ED:BE:A1:AC:DD:
        12:60:21:7C:9A:17:9E:80:53:E4:A6:82:1E:D8:1F:10:A8:54:8D:15:
        17:91:B5:60:C0:B9:85:7E:47:4F:64:E1:DF:13:A5:DA:EB:CE:98:25:
        35:40:08:76:7B:D9:4E:14:4A:28:44:CC
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
disable_11ac: N
disable_11ax: N
enable_ini: N
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
lar_disable: N
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
remove_when_gone: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: 3

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   94.287881] rndis_host 1-4:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:14.0-4, RNDIS device, <MAC 'usb0' [IF3]>
[  524.236091] e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Down
[ 1417.693566] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:52:00.0 failed with error -110

########## wireless info END ############
```

Anyone knows what to do? Thank you in advance

Comment: Is it a dual boot with Windows?

Comment: nope, only ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this probably by updating my kernel to 5.9

The effect doesn't apply immediately, as I've tried rebooting several times but it only worked after I shut it down and turn it on again after some time.

other than updating my kernel, I also updated some driver from nvidia-driver-450 to 455, don't know if this is related. Most likely the kernel update is the one fixed it.